# Socket closing during lifecycle changes

Tags: android, sockets, android-fragments

I'm trying to keep a socket open during lifecycle changes in a headless fragment with setRetainInstance(true); in onCreate. However, when my app comes back the following exception occurs.

```
E/Client: Receiving thread loop error
          java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
              at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
              at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:189)
              at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:250)
              at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:549)
              at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:481)
              at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
              at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
              at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:233)
              at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:145)
              at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:397)
              at com.gm.popper_6.ConnectionFragment$Client$ReceivingThread.run(ConnectionFragment.java:183)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here's the code for the fragment

```
public class ConnectionFragment extends Fragment {

    private InetAddress mGoAddress;
    private int mGoPort;
    private Client mClient;
    private static final String TAG = "Connection";
    private Server mServer;
    private Socket mSocket;
    private ConnectionFragmentListener listener;
    private String mMessage;

    public static ConnectionFragment newInstance(InetAddress address, int port){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("GoAddress", address);
        bundle.putInt("GoPort", port);
        ConnectionFragment fragment = new ConnectionFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return fragment;
    }

    public interface ConnectionFragmentListener{
        void onMessageRcvd(String message);
    }

    public void setConnectionFragmentListener(ConnectionFragmentListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    private void readBundle(Bundle bundle){
        if (bundle != null){
            mGoAddress = (InetAddress)bundle.getSerializable("GoAddress");
            mGoPort = bundle.getInt("GoPort");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        readBundle(getArguments());
        mGoAddress = (InetAddress) getArguments().getSerializable("GoAddress");
        mGoPort = getArguments().getInt("GoPort");

        mServer = new Server();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    //  THE SERVER CLASS
    private class Server{                               //DECLARATION

        ServerSocket mServerSocket = null;
        Thread mThread = null;

        public Server(){                                //CONSTRUCTOR
            mThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
            mThread.start();
        }

        public void tearDown(){
            mThread.interrupt();
            try {
                mServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "Error closing server socket");
            }
        }

        class ServerThread implements Runnable{

            @Override
            public void run() {

                //REMOVE OR COMMENT OUT FOR FINAL
                //android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

                try {
                    mServerSocket = new ServerSocket(mGoPort, 50, mGoAddress);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                    try {
                        mSocket = mServerSocket.accept();
                        Log.d(TAG, "Connected");

                        if (mClient == null){
                            mClient = new Client();
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //THE CLIENT CLASS
    private class Client {                              //DECLARATION

        private final String CLIENT_TAG = "Client";
        private Thread mSendThread;
        private Thread mRecThread;

        public Client() {                                   //CONSTRUCTOR

            Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Creating Client");

            mSendThread = new Thread(new SendingThread());
            mSendThread.start();
        }

        class SendingThread implements Runnable {           //an inner class of Client

            BlockingQueue<String> mMessageQueue;
            private int QUEUE_CAPACITY = 10;

            public SendingThread() {
                mMessageQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(QUEUE_CAPACITY);
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {

                mRecThread = new Thread(new ReceivingThread());
                mRecThread.start();

                while (true){

                    try {
                        String msg = mMessageQueue.take();
                        sendMessage(msg);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Sending loop interrupted, exiting");
                    }
                }
            }
        }           //closes SendingThread, an inner class of Client

        class ReceivingThread implements Runnable{          //an inner class of Client

            @Override
            public void run() {

                BufferedReader input;

                try {
                    //android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
                    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mSocket.getInputStream()));
                    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){

                        String messageStr = null;
                        messageStr = input.readLine();      //Line 183
                        if (messageStr!= null){
                            Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Read from the stream: " + messageStr);
                            mMessage = messageStr;
                            updateMessages(false);          
                        }
                        else{
                            Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "The null!!!");
                        }
                    }

                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(CLIENT_TAG, "Receiving thread loop error", e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }       //closes run method
        }           //closes ReceivingThread, an inner class of Client

        public void tearDown(){                         //a method of Client
            try {
                getSocket().close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void sendMessage(String msg){            //a method of Client
            try {
                Socket socket = getSocket();            //should return mSocket
                if (socket == null) {
                    Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Socket is null");
                } else if (socket.getOutputStream() == null) {
                    Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Socket output stream in null");
                }

                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(getSocket().getOutputStream())), true);
                out.println(msg);
                out.flush();
                mMessage = msg;
                updateMessages(true);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e){
                Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Unkown host", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "I/O exception", e);
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Error 3", e);
            }
            Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Message sent: " + msg);
        }       //closes sendMessage, a method of the inner Client class
    }           //closes Client class, an inner class of Connection

    private Socket getSocket() {
        return mSocket;
    }

    public synchronized void updateMessages(boolean local){
        Log.i(TAG, "Updating message: " + mMessage);

        if (local){
            mMessage = "me: " + mMessage;
        }
        else{
            mMessage = "them: " + mMessage;
        }

        if (listener!= null){
            listener.onMessageRcvd(mMessage);       
        }
    }       //closes updateMessages

    public void sendMessage(String msg){                            //CALL FROM MAIN ACTIVITY
        if(mClient != null){                                        //TO SEND A STRING MESSAGE
            mClient.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }

    public void tearDown(){
        mServer.tearDown();
        mClient.tearDown();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        tearDown();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}           //closes class declaration
```

And here's the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ChannelListener, DeviceActionListener,
        ConnectionInfoListener, ConnectionFragment.ConnectionFragmentListener{

    //CLASS DECLARATIONS
    public static final String TAG = "Popper";
    private WifiP2pManager manager;
    private Boolean isWifiP2pEnabled = false;
    ArrayList<Target> mTargets = new ArrayList<Target>(0);
    Target mTarget;
    TextView rcvd;
    TextView ip;
    EditText mssg;
    String goAddress = "";
    InetAddress goInetAddress;
    int prefixedPort;

    //declare and initialize an intent filter
    private final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    //private final IntentFilter serverFilter = new IntentFilter();

    private Channel channel;
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = null;
    private ConnectionInfoListener infoListener;
    private Intent serverServiceIntent;
    ConnectionFragment mConnection;

    //????
    public void setIsWifiP2pEnabled(boolean isWifiP2pEnabled) {
        this.isWifiP2pEnabled = isWifiP2pEnabled;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //register app w/p2p framework with call to initialize
        //channel is my apps connection to the p2p framework
        manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
        receiver = new P2pReceiver(manager, channel, this);
        rcvd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rcvd);
        rcvd.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        //initialize filter and setup to listen for the following broadcast intents
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

        Resources res = getResources();
        prefixedPort = res.getInteger(R.integer.GOport);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageRcvd(String message) {
        addLine(message);                       
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        receiver = new P2pReceiver(manager, channel, this);
        registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_items, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.atn_direct_discover:
                if (!isWifiP2pEnabled) {
                    NotificationToast.showToast(MainActivity.this, "Enable P2P!!!");
                    return true;
                }
                final TargetListFragment fragment = (TargetListFragment) getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
                fragment.onInitiateDiscovery();
                manager.discoverPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        NotificationToast.showToast(MainActivity.this, "Discovery initiated");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int reason) {
                        NotificationToast.showToast(MainActivity.this, "Discovery failed");
                    }
                });
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override                                   //this is associated with ChannelListener
    public void onChannelDisconnected() {       //removal causes error.
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo info) {

        goAddress = info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress();    //this returns a string rep of add.
        goInetAddress = info.groupOwnerAddress;                 //this returns actual inet add.
        ip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ip);
        mssg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mssg);

        ip.setText(goAddress + ":" + "8080");                   //display GO address and IP
        startConnectionFragment();
    }

    //this override method is triggered by TargetListFragment's DeviceActionListener
    @Override
    public void connect(WifiP2pConfig config) {
        manager.connect(channel, config, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                //maybe use this to gray out and disable the listview object that connected
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reason) {
            }
        });}

    public void startConnectionFragment(){
        mConnection = ConnectionFragment.newInstance(goInetAddress, prefixedPort);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(mConnection, "TAG_1");
        ft.commit();
        mConnection.setConnectionFragmentListener(this);
    }

    public void addLine(String line){
        final String msg = line;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                rcvd.append("\n" + msg);       
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTargetListClick(Target target) {
        mTarget = target;
    }

    public void stopServer() {

        if(serverServiceIntent != null)
        {
            stopService(serverServiceIntent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mConnection != null){
            //mConnection.tearDown();
        }
        stopServer();
    }

    public void SendMessage(View v){

        EditText txt = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.mssg);
        String str = txt.getText().toString();
        mConnection.sendMessage(str);

        txt.getText().clear();
    }
}
```

Could this have something to do with detaching when the app goes on pause or stop and not re-attaching when it comes back to life? Are there other things I should be considering?

Ultimately the app needs to keep communication open to about 5 or 6 devices over p2p. if there is a better strategy I'm open to suggestions. Thanks.

Update - So I've confirmed that both the onDestroy and onDetach methods of the fragment are firing when the main activity goes onStop. Since I have a method to close the sockets on death of the fragment they are getting closed. The big question now is how to keep the fragment alive?

Comment: View shouldn't be responsible for connection. That entity, which will do socket connection, should be injected to view (usually presenter) and should have completely different lifecycle.

Comment: That's kind of what I thought but I'm grasping at straws. Thanks for pointing me the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe create a helper class that will open/close sockets on behalf of other classes, such as that fragment, that helper class won't be subjected to any life cycle events, and can be kept running as long as the Application process is alive

Comment: I started out with a class that handled the communication, from opening a server socket, to a communication socket with sending and receiving threads but I still lost the sockets when the app went on pause or stop. Maybe you're talking about something different and it's still over my head. At the end of the day I want this app to control a simple GPIO which will turn the gate voltage on and off that in turn will switch a pneumatic cylinder. But it will have to control 5 or 6 of them and maintaining communication for 3 or 4 hours is pretty important.

Comment: when you no longer have any activities open and visible on screen, Android can and will kill your process, which will terminate your helper class. If you want something that will last longer then visible activities on screen, use a Service: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: I've spent a couple of weeks with a service to do the same thing but have a crash that I can't get past. I moved on to the headless fragment thinking that I could create multiple instances of it, each one maintaining a socket connection to a remote device over p2p. I've worked with a number of sources, including the android documentation and this one, http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html but the fragments do not perform as they claim with setRetainInstance(true); Part of the problem may be that I have to pass arguments.